# Parameterized SELECT queries via PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I'm trying to figure out how to do a parameterized query via PDO doing a SELECT, and right now I've got this code:

```
function user_login($username, $password) {
    $conn = connection_getConnection();

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username");
    $row = $stmt-> #WHAT DO I DO HERE?
    if (empty($row)) {

    }
}
```

So, I placed a comment on the line I'm kind of lost on. Please help me out from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) has some good examples.

For you:

```
function user_login($username, $password) {
    $conn = connection_getConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = :username";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $query = $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
    $rows = $query->fetchAll();
    if (empty($rows)) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Does that return an array of rows?

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud You should really check the manual.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: no; just updated my answer. And like jeroen said, you **really** should check the manual

Comment: @cegfault, I'll be honest, the manual is a lot of clutter for me personally, but apparently it's a good resource. I'll try to spend more time in the manual. It just seems like a ton of random user examples though. The information on the API seems limited. Am I misunderstanding how to use the manual? And please remember this, I'm coming from 12+ years of .NET development so the open-source community is very new to me.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: yes, there are a lot of good user examples, but near the top there is a section called "Examples" that are basic examples on the function.  Do try to spend more time with it an familiarize yourself with it.