# PHP mysql_real_escape_string is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird problem.

I have a table which has a title field.
I am inserting values into this title field using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Inserting is working fine for values with single quotes.
Some other place I am doing a select using title filed in the where clause as below

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title=mysql_real_escape_string(Girish's Photo);
```

This query is returning empty result set even when I  inserted Girish's Photo.

---- Editing to put some code

```
$photo_title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[photo_title]);<br/>
$sql = "INSERT INTO photos values($id,'$photo_title');<br/>
```

using this from a form I have inserted *Girish's Photo* into photo_title. It worked fine.
...
..
..

Then at some other place in PHP

```
$title="Girish's Photo";
$sql = "SELECT photo_id,photo_title FROM photos WHERE photo_title ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($title)."'" ;
```

But this query is returning empty result set.

Using phpMyAdmin, if I try to run the above query .. the result is empty. If I browse the table I see value Girish\'s Photo
Now if I run the query on phpMyAdmin replacing where clause with where photo_title='Girish\''s Photo'  I am getting the record.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is a php function

Comment: Your problem is wired? That is really weird.

Comment: As above. To use it in a php script you would have something like $query = "select * from table where title='".mysql_real_escape_string("Girish's Photo")."'";

Comment: Show some real code, what you show should shouldn't work.

Comment: OT: **Use of `mysql_*` extension is discouraged.** Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. And you should really use [prepared queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) instead of simply escaping.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $data = "Girish's Photo";

  $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE title='".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is a PHP-function, which should be used as follow:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE title='".mysql_real_escape_string("Girish's Photo")."'";
```

However, this is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently which I solved by using `htmlentites()` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string()` check it out in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp)

EDIT: this is a valid answer because he's using `mysql_real_escape_string()` in the wrong context in the first place. if you read the question, he's escaping a FILENAME and therefore he's not at risk of injection. If you're going to downvote at least say why..

Comment: It doesn't matter *what* he's escaping, it matters what context he's escaping for. For SQL context, you always escape using SQL functions. See http://kunststube.net/escapism.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you're going to want to use PDO for all queries. Primarily for the following reasons:

1. mysql_* is being deprecated.
2. It's not safe from SQL Injection.
3. PDO is capable of accessing numerous database engines making it much more flexible without changing the API.

Please take a look at this post to get a look at how to issue a SELECT using PDO.

[Parameterized SELECT queries via PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812650/parameterized-select-queries-via-pdo)

Comment: PDO isn't safe from SQL injection either **if used improperly**. The mysql_ API is perfectly safe from SQL injection **if used properly**.

Comment: he's not at risk of injection, it's a filename which already exists in the database, he's just having a problem with the quote.

Comment: @deceze, can you **edit** my answer and show me how you could use the *mysql_* API to prevent SQL Injection? Further, wouldn't point number one essentially be the most prominent reason not to use that API?

Comment: How to use the mysql_ API to prevent injection...? By applying `mysql_real_escape_string` correctly, that's what it's for. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @deceze, I think what I'm saying is the only way I've ever known to ensure that SQL Injection cannot occur is to parameterize the statement. However, bear in mind I come from 12+ years of .NET programming.

Comment: @Michael Then you as well should read http://kunststube.net/escapism. Note that parameterized statements *are* better, since they're easier to use and have additional functionality, and that you *shouldn't* use the mysql_ API since it's deprecated. But saying that it's inherently vulnerable to SQL injection is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The value in your database should ***not*** contain backslashes. That's why your query *doesn't match*. `Girish's Photo` does not match `Girish\'s Photo`. Sounds like you are a victim of [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php). Read [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) and get rid of them.